# Change output format of Pandas dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file containing all the fruits data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('fruit_list.csv')

grouped_by_places = df.groupby('Places')
sort_quad = grouped_by_places['Quality']
max_quad = sort_quad.max()
```

But when i do print(max_quad.to_dict()), i can only get the default output format for dictionary

```
{'A': 100, 'B': 70, 'C': 99, 'D': 84, 'E': 98, 'F': 89}
```

But i am trying to print the output as

```
A : 100.0
B : 70.0
C : 99.0
D : 84.0
E : 98.0
F : 89.0
```

Please help thanks for reading.

Comment: why don't you iterate the dict and print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) with `print` and `f-string`s:

```
for k,v in max_quad.items():
    print (f'{k} : {v}')
    
    A : 100
    B : 70
    C : 99
    D : 84
    E : 98
    F : 89
```

Comment: Woah, thank you very much! Didn't know about this method.